# Hyperlinks not working in PDF ver 1.2

Tags: c++, pdf, hyperlink

We have a old c++ programs that creates the PDF document. This program creates PDF Ver 1.2 document. PDF with text, tables and images were created fine, using this program.
Now I have to create a hyperlink in the pdf file. I have used the Streams and Objects as specified in the [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/PDF11.html) link(see, Example 4: Marking up link text using a /Link structure element). This link explains about the Pdf Ver-1.7. I guess these streams will not suit for Version 1.2.  Applying these streams and objects are not creating the hyperlink.

*So First, I want to make sure, does the PDF Ver-1.2 supports hyperlinks?*

I don't see any document related to Ver-1.2.  Can any one share, what kind of objects and stream need to create to construct hyperlink in Ver-1.2 ?

Thanks

Comment: Tagging was not part of PDF 1.2 but **Link** annotations were. Have you created the annotation (as indicated in your *Example 4*) and properly added the annotation to the annotations of the page (as that *Example 4* does not explicitly mention)?

Comment: You are correct, I have added annotation, But i missed to include /Annots tag in the beginning of file. After adding Annots, link is working fine, .Great Thanks.